# VTK render window image to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, vtk

In VTK I am able to use the following snippet to save the render window as an image. However, actually I want to get it directly as a numpy array (without writing then reading).

```
im = vtkWindowToImageFilter()
writer = vtkPNGWriter()
im.SetInput(renderWindow)
im.Update()
writer.SetInputConnection(im.GetOutputPort())
writer.SetFileName("file.png")
writer.Write()
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Check `vtk.util.numpy_support`.

Comment: @mmgp - thanks, but I haven't managed to figure how to get anything usable from the render window which I can pass to `vtk_to_numpy` :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe there is no need to involve `vtkXWriter` (where `X` is some format), except if you need the data in the `X` format. After you define the window from which you want to export its contents as an image, you can proceed to get a VTK image and work with that.

```
from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy

...

vtk_rw = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()

...

vtk_win_im = vtk.vtkWindowToImageFilter()
vtk_win_im.SetInput(vtk_rw)
vtk_win_im.Update()

vtk_image = vtk_win_im.GetOutput()

width, height, _ = vtk_image.GetDimensions()
vtk_array = vtk_image.GetPointData().GetScalars()
components = vtk_array.GetNumberOfComponents()

arr = vtk_to_numpy(vtk_array).reshape(height, width, components)

...
```